# System call tracing

Tags: process, system-calls

I am working on system call tracing for host based IDS, i need to trace a process as soon as it entered in the system (a new entry in `/proc`). Is there any interrupt or signal or kernel datastructure from where this information can be extracted.

Comment: @JMoore Please elaborate and make that an answer.

Comment: What operating system and computer architecture?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use the `audit` infrastructure. Install the `auditd` package and add rules for the system calls you want to trace and for which process/user or other criteria.